# What are the excess baggage fees on Qatar Airways flights from the US to Africa?

Tags: usa, luggage, qatar-airways

I am traveling from the US to Entebbe this week with Qatar Airways and I expect my baggage to be overweight. Now I am confused at the applicable rate for excess baggage. Is it $40 per kg in the table that applies to me since I am traveling to Africa or is it the $50 that applies since I am traveling from the US?

Answer (score 4):

Since you're travelling from the US, your first leg is the one that determines the [fees](http://www.qatarairways.com/ca/en/excess-baggage-rates.page) in this case.  Note that the fees are per piece for the second table (not per kg) and that the fee will vary depending on whether you booked through a QA office (65USD) or online (50USD).

[image]

Comment: No, that doesn't have to do with where the ticket was originally booked. It's $50 if you prepay the fee during online check-in, or $65 if you pay at the airport.